# get Jsonobject response item

Tags: android, json

I am trying to pass a jsonobject response id item between activities but it is not appending the value of the id parameter.

Here is my code

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         Intent sendsms Intent(FirstSignUp.this,SmsCodePage.class);
         sendsms.putExtra("id", result.toString());
         startActivity(sendsms);

            }
```

Next Activity code:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String idata = extras.getString("id");
```

calling it:

```
user.put("id", idata);
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: `result.toString()` is redundant... It's already a string, not a JSONObject

Comment: Is the problem in `idata` or is it in `user`?

Comment: The promem is in idata.

Comment: What is returned is not the specified string but the whole json response